# Duplicate Integer

Tags: integer, duplicates

I'm studying computer science and I've been asked this question:

An array of length n+1 is populated with integers in the range [1, n]. Find a duplicate integer (just one, not all) in linear time with O(1) space. The array is read-only and may not be modified. Variation: what if the array may be written into but must be left unmodified by the algorithm?

It would be great if someone could help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming array is 1-indexed :

```
n=size;
x=a[n];y=a[a[n]];
while(x!=y)                       
{
    x=a[x];y=a[a[y]];
}
y=n;
while(x!=y)
{
    x=a[x];y=a[y];
}
printf("DUPLICATE: %d",y);
```

This technique is known as Pollard's rho method.